# Device.uuid plugins notification not displaying cordova iOS app

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, uuid

I have a cordova ios app. I use the UUID frequently in my app but now its not working it gets stuck at the alert that displays it.

```
onDeviceReady: function() {
    alert("On device Ready"); // Hits this and thats it
    alert(device.window.uuid); //does not display this and does not go on
    app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
},
```

as well as when I do:
`alert(device.window.uuid);`

`var pushNotification = window.plugins.pushNotification;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
alert(device.uuid);
```

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/cordova_device_device.md.html#device.uuid

If that doesn't work and you are building locally, make sure to run:

```
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.device
```

Comment: everything was fine but then I switched versions of `cordova` to 3.3.0

Comment: did you install the device plugin? In 3.3.0 everything is a plugin, even the parts used to be core.

Comment: its included in my config.xml

Comment: are you using build.phonegap.com or building locally?

Comment: cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.device

Comment: When you build locally, config.xml is not used for plugins. As stated above, you have to add the plugin using the cli. And also be advised that the plugin is installed for the platform only after you launch "cordova prepare ios" or "cordova build ios".